# How to refocus the Input-Field once the Toast is displayed

Tags: lightning, toast

I have an InputField, when the length of the String entered in the InputField becomes 0, it should display a toast and on closing the Toast, the Focus should come back to InputField?

Here I am able to display a Toast Properly but due to toast, I am losing focus from the InputField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a duration attribute in lightning toast method.
Once the toast method is fired using.
toastEvent.fire();

you can use javascript setTimeout method of the same duration and In that method, you can use javascript to set focus on particular input with particular id like this.

```
document.getElementById("InputId").focus();
```

or you can use cmp.get("v.Input"); to get the input and set it focus in similar way.